# free() detecting heap corruption

Tags: c++, free, memory-corruption

When using Visual Studio 2013 heap corruption is detected on calling `free()`.
It is not detected on Linux.

My code seems to run fine until it hits the free function. I call free many times, but in one specific instance, it causes a window to pop up saying HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED.

I've allocated memory to store pointers to strings(words) for two sets of words. For the first set of words, upon freeing them, no error message is given.

For the second set of words, upon freeing them, the error message pops up.

Here is the code for the first set of words, I made an array of words called arrayFictionary. The function takes a pointer to the array of pointers and adds on new words. No error message is given upon freeing(arrayFictionary).

```
void ConvertFictionary(char*** parrayFictionary, char* fictionary) {
    char * pTemp = 0;
    int32_t count = 1;
    // put first fictionary word into an array
    if(!(pTemp=strtok(fictionary, "\n"))) {//if the dictionary end is reached,
        (*parrayFictionary)[count-1] = pTemp;               // exit while loop
        goto skipD;
    }
    *parrayFictionary = (char**) realloc(*parrayFictionary, (count + 1)*sizeof(char*));
    (*parrayFictionary)[count-1] = pTemp;
    count++;
    while(1) {// put fictionary words into an array, exit when done
        if(!(pTemp=strtok(NULL, "\n"))) {//if the dictionary end is reached,
            (*parrayFictionary)[count-1] = pTemp;         // exit while loop
            break;
        }
        *parrayFictionary = (char**) realloc(*parrayFictionary, (count + 1)*sizeof(char*));
        (*parrayFictionary)[count-1] = pTemp;
        count++;
    }
skipD:
    return;
}
```

Here is the code for allocating an array for my second set of words called arrayFarticle. Same method is used with slight differences. Error message results upon calling free(arrayFarticle).

```
void ConvertFarticle(char*** parrayFarticle, char* farticle)
{
char * pTemp = 0;
int32_t count = 1;
// put first farticle word into an array
if(!(pTemp=strtok(farticle, "0123456789.,;: '\"\n!@#$%%^&*()_-+=|\\[]{} <>?/~`’"))) //if the farticle end is reached, exit while loop
    {
        (*parrayFarticle)[count-1] = pTemp;
        goto skipA;
    }
if(strlen(pTemp)>=2)
{
    *parrayFarticle = (char**) realloc(*parrayFarticle, sizeof(char*)*count + sizeof(char*)*2);
    (*parrayFarticle)[count-1] = pTemp;
    count++;
}

while(1) // put farticle words into an array, exit when done
{   
    if(!(pTemp=strtok(NULL, "0123456789.,;: '\"\n!@#$%%^&*()_-+=|\\[]{}<>?/~`’"))) //if the farticle end is reached, exit while loop
    {
        (*parrayFarticle)[count-1] = pTemp;
        break;
    }
    if(strlen(pTemp)>=2)
    {
        *parrayFarticle = (char**) realloc(*parrayFarticle, sizeof(char*)*count + 1);
        (*parrayFarticle)[count-1] = pTemp;
        count++;
    }
}
skipA:
return;
```

}

I honestly don't know what's going on. I made sure that arrayFarticle isn't being written past its allocated limit.

Comment: `free` won't *cause* corruption, but corruption may not be detected until a `free` is executed.

Comment: Warning: [ThreeStarProgrammer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) detected.

Comment: @YakkYour comment was very helpful. You could of told me to use references as an argument. But instead you flat out gave me an insult. People like you are why I come on here to get help from more experience programmers. I'm glad you have an extensive vocabulary for handing out insults to people.

Answer (score 0):

Your last call to `realloc` results in `*parrayFarticle` pointing to a block with an odd (in the mathematical sense) size, and (quite likely) too small.

Comment: Wow I'm dumb. Thank you. I realized I had put sizeof(char*)*count +1 instead of sizeof(char*)*count + sizeof(char*)....

Comment: Question: I would have never known this issue if I had never ran this on visual studio, how would I know if I was on Linux? The code never crashed.

Comment: @LivePresently Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org). Its memcheck tool an check for memory corruption errors extremely thoroughly.

Comment: @LivePresently https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/ is also useful, and often faster than valgrind. Both of these tools instrument and catch the error at runtime rather than as a static analysis pass.